# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: react-native

Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.
This error is located at:

code here`[Appcontainer-> index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpXXP.png)

[App.js code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45r1e.png)

[main.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdAqG.png)

I used Expo to run this react-native project

Comment: Please copy the error message as text.

Comment: in App (at Router.js:122)
    in Router (at AppContainer/index.js:14)
    in Provider (at AppContainer/index.js:13)
    in AppContainer (at main.js:11)
    in Root (at App.js:15)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at App.js:14)
    in MyApplication (at withExpoRoot.js:20)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:19)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
-

Comment: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5716:10 in createFiberFromTypeAndProps
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5744:4 in createFiberFromElement
- ... 23 more stack frames from framework internals

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: shared screen short at top

Comment: above mentioned link

Comment: Please add the additional info directly to the question and remove the comments afterwards.